# Best way to apply dynamic domain to many2many field in Odoo8?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have a model in which the user can select the breed of a dog (`dog_breed`, a Selection field). Then, in the same model, I have a Many2many field (`dogs`) in which the user can add dogs. But I want that when the user adds a dog, he is only able to select among the dogs whose breed is the one selected in the `Selection` field.

```
<field name="dog_breed"/>
<field name="dogs" domain="[('breed', '=', dog_breed)]"/>
```

When you add an element to a Many2many, first you see a list of the available records, to select one of them if the one you are looking for already exists. What I need is to apply a domain to that list.

> Example:
>
> An user selects *foxterrier* in the Selection field `dog_breed`. Now
>   he adds an element in the Many2many `dogs`. A list with all the
>   available dogs will be opened, but I want to show a list with all the
>   available *foxterriers*. To do that, I wrote the above code, but it is
>   not working at all.

However, if I modify the code this way:

```
<field name="dog_breed"/>
<field name="dogs" domain="[('breed', '=', 'foxterrier')]"/>
```

It works perfect. Is it possible to manage this from XML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic domain must be applied in Python code, in this case isn't even necessary to use *onchanges* to return the required domain, I've only had to cut my domain to the definition of the `Many2many` field in Python:

```
dogs = fields.Many2many(
    comodel_name='dog',
    relation='mss_dog_rel',
    column1='mss_id',
    column2='dog_id',
    string='Dogs',
    domain="[('breed', '=', dog_breed)]",
)
```